# Statistical comparisons between large data sets

Tags: mean, large-data, nonparametric

Currently, I am looking for the correct (or suitable) statistical method to compare 4 very large datasets (n = 31 million each), that are based on an experiment where a continuous variable was measured in response to 4 different discrete temperatures.

Each data set has pretty much the same median, and the means and standard deviations do not vary much.  However, each data set is not normally distributed, and are only vaguely lognormally distributed.

I am trying to determine a way to test the null hypothesis that increased temperatures do not affect the mean of each data set.

Am I right in my thinking that ANOVA would not be suitable, (nor any parametric test)?  I have looked at the non parametric Kruskal-Wallis statistic, but are not sure if this is a suitable.

So my questions are, am I correct in my assumptions above? and what would be a suitable statistical method to prove the null hypothesis as described above?

Comment: Why do you think ANOVA wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: Doesn't it require a normal distribution? (or close to)

Comment: No. It assumes that the errors, as estimated by the residuals, are normal. It does not assume that the variables are normal.

Comment: ah, ok, but would it be suitable for comparing 4 datasets as large as I have them?

Comment: If ANOVA is a possibility, which type of ANOVA would best suit?

Comment: If the data you mention is all that you have, then it's a one way ANOVA.

Comment: hmmm that is the one I was thinking of

Answer (score 5):

1) As I noted in comments, ANOVA requires that the error, as measured by the residuals, be normal. It does not require that the data (or any particular variable) be normal

2) When you have a lot of data the statistical problem you run into is that even a tiny difference will be statistically significant. This is not a problem with ANOVA or any particular technique, it is a problem with p values and significance testing (one of several).  (I say statistical problem to distinguish from problems with memory, run time and so on).

3) Since you say in your question that the means don't vary much, you may not need *any* statistical analysis. You can simply present the means at each temperature (with standard deviations) and say "although with a large N, such differences might be statistically significant, they are of no practical importance". You could also include a graph - perhaps a parallel boxplot or one of its variants.

Comment: Thank you for this - your third point in particular as we've found significant standard deviations (eg mean of 6, standard deviation of 3)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers you should probably learn more about the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) (an important enough theorem that I have a [cross-stitch](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos?pid=5841570734277964962&oid=105776982242457853811) of it hanging on my wall).

The short version of the CLT is that when you are doing statistics comparing means and you use a test that assumes normality (anova, linear regression, etc.) and if the residuals do not actually come from a normal, but your sample size is large enough, then the answers will still be approximately correct.  How large is large enough depends on the actual distribution of the residuals, but many common cases use rules of thumb of around 30 to 40 being considered "large", even if your data represents very skewed residuals, 31 million observations would probably still be large enough to give a good approximation.

This means that practical significance (as Peter Flom mentions) is probably a much bigger issue than non-normality for your sample size.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you should run a simulation to see the behavior of sample means from a log normal distribution behave.

A standard deviation of 3 when you're running million+ observations is quite small.